# Как улучшить отображение шрифтов в WPF?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

Здравствуйте, столкнулся с данной проблемой, гуглил – не смог найти ответа.

Пишу на C# WPF .Net 4.0

Использую шрифт Roboto

Эта фотка на Windows 10 (1920*1080) разрешение монитора.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Ссылка на фото: https://i.stack.imgur.com/pRDx4.png

Эта фотка Windows 7 (1366*768) разрешение монитора.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Ссылка на фото: https://i.stack.imgur.com/a1Dpv.png

**Лучше открыть фото, так будет виднее и понятнее**

Как сделать так, чтоб шрифты отображались корректно? Как на Windows 10 (1920*1080)

Пробовал так:

```
<Window TextOptions.TextFormattingMode="Display" ...... />
```

И тогда даже на Windows 10 (1920*1080) отображается как на Windows 7 (1366*768)

Comment: А с другими шрифтами проблема есть?

Comment: Не пробовал, т.к. именно эти нужны...

Comment: Но как видите, если шрифт большого размера, то он лучше отображается

Comment: А вы всё же попробуйте. Вы хотите изучить проблему, или чтобы кто-то подогнал готовое заклинание?

Comment: Я обычный магл, поэтому думал поделятся заклинанием умелые волшебники=)

Comment: Опытные волшебники спят :-\ Или они плохо читали эту часть гримуара. Так что давайте сами допишем нужную страницу. Попробуйте и правда ради интереса с другим шрифтом.

Comment: Кстати, может, у вас в свойствах системы отключён _антиалиасинг_ (это слово точно было в нужном заклинании).

Comment: Посмотрите, что на вашей системе говорит `RenderCapability.Tier` и почитайте вот это: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742196%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Еще поиграйтесь с этими параметрами вместе:

```
TextOptions.TextFormattingMode="Ideal"
TextOptions.TextRenderingMode="ClearType"
TextOptions.TextHintingMode="Auto"
```

Ну и вообще ощущение что на Windows 7, крутящейся на виртуалке `ClearType` отключен